# Allow only certain roles access to custom module in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am having trouble getting this working correctly. I have created an order form module for Drupal and I need to control access to it. I noticed that this order form was accessible without being logged in if I browse directly to `http://example.com/orders/order-form` I have been looking around and I think I am on the right track but missing something simple. I have created the function below in my order-form module:

```
function order_form_permission() {
  return array(
    'order form permission' => array(
      'title' => t('Order Form Permissions'),
      'description' => t('Deny access to certain users.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Then in the same file to create the page I use this function:

```
function order_form_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['orders/order-form'] = array(
        'title' => 'Order Form',
        'descriptions' => 'A form for ordering products',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('order_form_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('order_form_permission')
    );
    return $items;
}
```

The `page arguments` array contains the call to the form that is generated.

I have set permissions for certain user roles already in `admin/people/permissions` It shows access denied when I am not logged in which is what I want. But when I browse to the page logged in as the main administrator I can see it, which is what I want.

The problem is when I try to log in as another user or account that has the role assigned to it I want to be able to access the order form it will say Access Denied. I must be missing something simple here hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: You need to add 'access callback' in your hook_menu implementation and set the order_form_permission as a value. For more details, refer to hook_form on api.drupal.org

Comment: @JoshiConsultancy it is still not working. It will allow everyone to access it regardless of set permissions

Comment: Of course, you need to check the user roles and other stuff in order_form_permission(). This is why we define a custom function for custom condition for access!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to define the access callback, it defaults to the user_access() function which is powered by the hook_permissions from drupal.

The access arguments in the hook menu should be the same as the array key in the hook permission. 
So try removing the underscores from the

`'access arguments' => array('order_form_permission')`